# Startup black screen issue

Tags: error-handling

When I start up my laptop after installing ubuntu all I get is a black screen with a dash in the top left corner  I  can't  start up my  laptop  because of this

Please help

Comment: Explain your problem correctly........Like which system you are using and what is the OS you installed etc.......

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have?

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!